# Scala trait: val/def and require

Tags: scala, illegalargumentexception

The following code throws `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
trait T{
  val x: Long
  require(x > 0)
}

object T extends App{
  val y = new T{ val x = 42L }
}
```

while the following does not:

```
trait T{
  def x(): Long
  require(x() > 0)
}

object T extends App{
  val y = new T{ def x() = 42L }
}
```

Why is that? When is `require()` called? Why is the `val` even defined at that point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `def` declares a method, which is put in the class by the compiler, so it exists as soon as it is compiled. In order to return something, a method has to run through to the point at which it actually returns something, so there is no problem in your second example.

`val` declares an "immutable value", although it still has to be initialised, before which point it holds the default value for its type - in this case, 0. This initialisation takes place after the constructor of `trait T` runs, unless you change your example to use early initialization:

```
val y = new { val x = 42L } with T
```