# Preconditioning (require) an uninitialized value's property in a Scala trait

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception, require, traits, illegalargumentexception

Given the below trait, instance `a` throws `NullPointerException`:

```
trait T {
  val l: List[Int]

  require(l.size > 1)
}

case class A(list: List[Int]) extends T {
  override val l: List[Int] = list
}

val a = A(List(1,2))
```

Based on [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228108/scala-trait-val-def-and-require), I tried the below variations for `T`:

```
trait T {
  def l(): List[Int]

  require(l().size > 1)
}

trait T {
  val l: List[Int]
  lazy val s: Int = l.size

  require(s > 1)
}

trait T {
  val l: List[Int]
  def s: Int = l.size

  require(s > 1)
}
```

but all of them gives `NullPointerException`.

Is there a way to use precondition (`require` clause) for an uninitialized value's property in a trait or do I have to copy the precondition(s) to all classes implementing the trait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this as follow:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait T {
  def l: List[Int]
  require(l.size > 1)
}

case class A(l: List[Int]) extends T

val a = A(List(1,2))


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait T
defined class A
a: A = A(List(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `l` to be a `def`, one way of getting around the problem would be the following:

```
case class A(list: List[Int]) extends {
    val l: List[Int] = list
} with T
```

Comment: I accepted @curious' reply as answer simply because its brevity, but yours is working as well.

Comment: @bugfoot, I hope you realize that those two answers work for very different reasons and so have different applicability?

Comment: @SergGr Could you elaborate on the main differences please?

Comment: @bugfoot, the main difference is that if you want to extend 2 different traits `T1` and `T2` that happen to have different field names (`l` and `list`) and both traits do some checks, you can't make it work using the other answer's way but you still can make it work using this way. Also according to my understanding of the [spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-definitions) the behavior in the other answer is not guaranteed (although it is not likely to change in practice) while this one is guaranteed (see section 5.1.6 "Early Definitions")

Comment: @SergGr Thanks for the explanation. Actually I just needed to extend 2 different traits, both of which has checks, and I could do it using Dennis' answer. Why can't two answer be selected I wonder...

Comment: @bugfoot, I specifically wrote "_2 different traits T1 and T2 that happen to have different **field names** (`l` and `list`)_". Obviously if you have 2 different **fields** you still can use the other answer, but if the same logical field has 2 different names in 2 traits (which happens if code is written by more than one person or if they come from different libraries), I'm not aware of a way to make it work using another answer.